# Is it possible to dynamically create a dependency injection token and link it to an instance of a class?

Tags: angular

Say I have a component that has internal services as dependencies that are newed up, with a shared configuration object:

```
@Component({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: SomeService,
      useClass: SomeService,
      deps: [
        SomeOtherService,
      ]
  ...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() config: Configuration;

  constructor (private service: SomeService) {}
  ngOnInit () {
    this.service.config = this.config;
  }
  ...
}
```

...

If I need an external service or component to have access to that specific instance of that component's internal service, how can I do that?

I know I could just use some sort of stateful service that stores references based on the configuration's name like:

```
  ngOnInit () {
    this.service.config = this.config;
    this.dependencyService.store(this.config.name, { someService: this.service });
  }
```

then an external service could just do:

```
  this.service = this.dependencyStore.get('some-name').someService;
```

But I was wondering, is there any way I could dynamically generate a dependency injection token based off of the name from the configuration object, and store the instance of `SomeService` in that?  That way I would not have to manually manage storing instances of the service object, and the external service or component that needs that instance of the service could just use a constructor function:

```
constructor (@Inject(SOME_NAME) private service: SomeService) {}
```

...  But I am unclear how to define `SOME_NAME` dynamically based off of the configuration object in the component and provide the specific instance of the service   that the component new'd up using `useClass` to the injector...  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to define `SOME_NAME` dynamically? Do you want to configure it on both ends (in component and module) dynamically? If yes, what is the benefit of dynamically changing it? I assume you actually want to provide only the service which matches some configuration property. In order to do this I suggest you to use a factory in your module and provide to a constant token whichever service is needed.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus Sorry if my post wasn't clear..  As I showed in my example, I currently am storing the instances of the services in a key value store named `dependencyStore`..  So the idea is the component (that news up the services) has a configuration object with a name, and those services that it news up are stored in the dependency store under the name property of the component's config.  Then in other parts of the app can access those services by looking up by that specific key.  `SOME_NAME` was just random, but what would have been the value of the component's config name property.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus, so I just was curious if there was a way to do this with the injector so that I wouldn't need to use this `dependencyStore` object..  If the injector could just hold the instance of the service, available via an injector token that is created based off of the name property of the config, then that would accomplish my goal.  I am also a little unclear what you meant about using a factory in the module...  This component is used in multiple places (different configs with different names), so I would want to be able to access those services created by each component instance.